# C pointer difference Char Int

Tags: c, pointers

the code bellow works as it needs to work.

```
  void TstPointer(int *Pointer)
    {
        *Pointer = 3;   
    }

    int main()
    {
        int number = 1;
        int *ptr  = &number;

        TstPointer(ptr);

        printf("%d\n", number);
    }
```

But when i switch types to char it doesnt work.

```
void TstPointer(char *Pointer)
{
    *Pointer = "Hell1"; 
}

int main()
{
    char *Hello  = "Hello";
    TstPointer(Hello);
    printf("%s\n", Hello);
}
```

warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  *Pointer = "Hell1";

Comment: `'H'` is a character (`char`), `"Hell1"` is a string (array of `char`)

Comment: Please study how pointers and strings work in your beginner-level C programming book.

Answer (score 0):

While doing `*Pointer = "Hell1";` your compiler warned you. You chose to ignore that which possibly invokes the [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In general , to copy to a pointer, use `strcpy()` but in that case, that will cause problem, as `Pointer` points to a *string literal* which you're not allowed to change.

You need to make sure that the memory is writable before trying to write *into* that memory location. Either use memory allocator function, or create an array and make the pointer point to the start of the array.

Answer (score 0):

In your `TstPointer` method, when you do `*Pointer = "Hell1";`, you are generating the warning.

This is because, if `Pointer` is a char pointer, then `*Pointer` is a char variable. And you are assigning a string constant to a char variable which is wrong.

To solve this issue, I think you ought to use a double pointer in the function parameter as pass the address (of the pointer) in the `main`!

EDIT:

You are getting the warning because when you assign a string constant to a variable (char pointer or array, usually), that variable stores the address of the beginning of the string constant. Now, when the lvalue is not char pointer type, but is just a char variable, some implicit conversion takes place to assign (fit) the "address" into a normal char variable, which in turn gives the warning. But, we know `char` cannot accommodate a memory address, and thus will usually result in a segfault when printed!

Comment: that or strcpy(Pointer,"Hell1");

Comment: @skrtbhtngr  expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
 void TstPointer(char **Pointer)

Comment: In the main, `TstPointer(&Hello);`.

Comment: @Turtle Using `strcpy()` wouldn't be safe as it would be overwriting the `"Hello"` from `main()`.

Comment: @Turtle it is what i am trying to do. overwrite variable in main()

Comment: @TripeHound he is trying to overwrite "Hello" from `main()`.

Comment: @turtle He (should) be trying to replace what `ptr` in main points to, but shouldn't be overwriting what may be read-only memory  (the string `"Hello"`).

Comment: I agree, but that isn't what he is trying to do. He is trying to overwrite what could be read only memory. Regardless, we are arguing over semantics at this point

Comment: I _suspect_ what he's trying to do is/should be replace what `ptr` points at, which means he would need to pass in a `char**`. which is the correct analogy to trying to alter an `int` by passing in an `int*`.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the reference of `Hello` to your method (`&Hello`) as you do with int -

`int *ptr  = &number;
TstPointer(ptr);`

Comment: `void TstPointer(char **Pointer)
{
 *Pointer = "Hello"; 
}

int main()
{
 char *Hello  = "Hello World";
 TstPointer(&Hello);
 printf("%s\n", Hello);
}`   So here how i solved it based on your answers thaks guys!